# How do I get a more precise current, video and start time with YouTube iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube, youtube-api

At the moment my start time and end time for an embedded video is put in seconds. However, I know it's possible to be much more precise than this (when I go to my playlists in YouTube, I can edit the start and end times of each video, and YouTube lets me drag the player head around and displays milliseconds - although of course you can't move ms by ms).

My app needs precision, and both `getCurrentTime` and `seekTo` only take seconds as arguments. How does YouTube manage to be more precise? A 1/4 second precision would be fine enough for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Youtube API seekTo() in float seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14461176/youtube-api-seekto-in-float-seconds)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify fractions of seconds using a float number

I think this answer and this example may be useful

[Youtube API seekTo() in float seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14461176/youtube-api-seekto-in-float-seconds)